# Google Maps Api - multiple items in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am trying to display infowindows that contain an elevation chart plotted from GeoJson data and also the type of the clicked GeoJson feature (Tip_drum property). It seems that I have managed to put the elevation_chart into the infowindows, but I cannot get the other property.

The code for my application is:

```
var elevator;
var map;
var chart;
var infowindow;

//loading the visualization API
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['columnchart']});

//initializing the map
function initialize() {
var options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.701991, 22.624884),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

//loading the GeoJSON file, which contains the Tip_drum attribute
trasee = new google.maps.Data();
map.data.loadGeoJson('http://googledrive.com/host/0B55_4P6vMjhITEU4Ym9iVG8yZUU/trasee.geojson');

//creating the infowindow content
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{content: '<div class = "corp" style="width: 260px; height: 200px">' + '<div id = "elevation_chart">' +
'</div>' + '</div>'}
)

//adding events
map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng)
    infowindow.setMap(map)
    if (event.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'LineString') {
        drawPath(event.feature.getGeometry().getArray());
    }
});

map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
map.data.revertStyle();
  map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 8, strokeColor: 'blue'});
});

map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
map.data.revertStyle();
});
 elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();     
}

//creating the functions needed for Elevation Charts
function drawPath(path) {
chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));

var pathRequest = {
    'path': path,
    'samples': 256
};

elevator.getElevationAlongPath(pathRequest, plotElevation);
}

function plotElevation(results, status) {
if (status != google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
    return;
}
var elevations = results;

var elevationPath = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    elevationPath.push(elevations[i].location);
}

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
}

document.getElementById('elevation_chart').style.display = 'block';
chart.draw(data, {
    height: 150,
    width: 260,
    legend: 'none',
    titleY: 'Elevation (m)'
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Full application code in JSFiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/j54gLjap/9/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't display the trails anymore.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not a link to an external site.  What happened to the last version of this question?  You aren't going to be able to access the DOM in the infowindow until the `domready` event has fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the type also as argument to drawPath:

```
drawPath(event.feature.getGeometry().getArray(),
         event.feature.getProperty('Tip_drum'));
```

then use the argument in drawPath:

```
function drawPath(path, type) {
    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));

    //creates a textNode based on the type and inserts it before the chart
    document.getElementById('elevation_chart').parentNode
       .insertBefore(document.createTextNode(type),
                     document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));

    var pathRequest = {
        'path': path,
            'samples': 256
    };

    elevator.getElevationAlongPath(pathRequest, plotElevation);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j54gLjap/10/

Comment: Your method works fine in this case, but if I want to add more than one attribute (for example, description and other details), how can I separate all the text nodes with line breaks>

Comment: You may also use element-nodes with insertBefore, so e.g. you may insert a `<br/>`-element after a textNode to get a line-break. Of course you also may place the textNodes into a block-element like p or div and insert this element. See: [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)